# JavaScript hoisting and scope

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

why the foo() function logs `undefined`?
The first `text` variable is a global variable so `foo()` should have an access to it.

```
var text = "outside";

function foo() {
    console.log(text);
    var text = "inside";
}

foo();
```

Comment: Do return text; and alert(foo())

Comment: @Jonasw don't use `alert` for debugging statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though the `var` statement is after the `console.log()` statement, the declaration is hoisted to the beginning of the function. So this declares a local variable that shadows the global variable. But the initialization doesn't happen until you actually get to the statement, which is after the `console.log()` statement.

So your function is equivalent to:

```
function foo() {
    var text;
    console.log(text);
    text = 'inside';
}
```

If you didn't use the `var` declaration then you would continue to use the global variable, and the reassignment wouldn't happen until after the `console.log()`.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that javascript does not actually hoist. This behavior is actually the result of the first pass of compiling process. The resulting behavior is the same as hoisting, however, technically speaking, nothing actually gets hoisted.

Comment: @Barmar Make sure to note that removint the var from the foo() function makes foo use the text global variable

Comment: @mhodges What's the effective difference between that and hoisting?

Comment: I believe true hoisting actually moves the declarations in the code before the compiler reads it. In Javascript, however, the compiler takes 2 passes. One to grab the LHS declarations and one to do RHS evaluation/assignment, giving the same behavior/functionality as hoisting.

Comment: @mhodges Everyone just calls this hoisting. Since the behavior is indistinguishable, the internal mechanism is unimportant.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was just about to mention that: I think the term has shifted to mean the behavior, and not the actual physical hoisting of the code.

Comment: Kyle Simpson does a phenomenal job explaining how the compiler/execution phases work. https://john-dugan.com/hoisting-in-javascript/